# String formatting in Python?

Tags: python, string, variables, formatting

I'm having some difficulty getting string formatting working - how do i get a string inside here?

```
VARIABLEHERE = "myToken"
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/1/users/VARIABLEHERE', '', {
"X-Parse-Application-Id":
```

})
    result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
    print result

I've tried puttin this % where VARIABLEHERE is but i don't know where this part goes % VARIABLEHERE. outside the curly brackets or inside the parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do:

```
VARIABLEHERE = "myToken"
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/1/users/%s'%VARIABLEHERE, '', {
"X-Parse-Application-Id"
})
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

or you can try:

```
connection.request('GET', '/1/users/{0}'.format(VARIABLEHERE),#more stuff
```